# Adding NSViews to NSScrollview - Mac OSX

Tags: macos, nsview, nsscrollview, nsimageview

I'm trying to add multiple images of NSImageView to the NSScrollView. When I add it as a subview, the scrollview doesn't seem to scroll and when I add it as a document view I can see only one image. Any ideas or sample code on how to get this working? Suggestions pls. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that your framing is done wrong, or you forgot to set frame of the document view.
Below is an example of adding stuff to the scroll view.

```
float allHeight = 0.f; // Consider starting from the top
float xOffset = 0.f; // Offset addjustments
float yOffset = 20.f;
float spacing = 5.f; // Spacing
float attachementCellHeight = 40.f; 
// Values above are random :)

for (MyObject *obj in SetOfObjects) {
    NSView *attachementView = [[[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(xOffset, allHeigth, self.bounds.size.width - xOffset, attachementCellHeight)] autorelease];
    [self.documentView addSubview:attachementView];
    allHeigth += attachementCellHeight;
    allHeigth += spacing;
}
allHeigth+=yOffset;
self.documentView.frame = NSMakeRect(1, 1, self.bounds.size.width - 2, allHeigth);
```